# GitHub pull request title does not change automatically

Tags: github-actions, pull-request

I just wanted to set up a workflow on GitHub to ensure that pull request titles satisfy some given regex. To do so, I used [this GitHub action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/check-pull-request-title) from the marketplace:

```
  check-title:
    name: Ensure PR title is first line of conventional commit
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: Slashgear/action-check-pr-title@v4.3.0
        with:
          regexp: "(?:build|ci|docs|feat|fix|perf|refactor|test)!?: [a-z]{1}.+[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}"
          helpMessage: "Please use PR title being first line of a conventional commit, see https://www.conventionalcommits.org/en/v1.0.0/"
```

To test it, I created a pull request with the title `first attempt`, being absolutely aware that this does not match my regex. The workflow failed as expected. After that, I changed the pull request title to `ci: automatically check PR title`.

However, after re-running the failed pipeline, it still fails with the following message:

```
Error: Pull Request title "first attempt" failed to pass match regexp - /(?:build|ci|docs|feat|fix|perf|refactor|test)!?: [a-z]{1}.+[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}/
```

Only when I add a new commit, the pull request title is actually updated.

Can someone explain this behaviour? I don't want to commit something just to let a workflow pass that does not do anything with the code or its commit messages.

Comment: Seems like there is an [issue](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/issues/1204) active in github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check that your workflow is listening to the right events, [the doc says](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request):

> By default, a workflow only runs when a pull_request event's activity
> type is opened, synchronize, or reopened. To trigger workflows by
> different activity types, use the types keyword. For more information,
> see "Workflow syntax for GitHub Actions."

I would suggest the following:

```
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [assigned, edited, opened, synchronize, reopened]
```

Comment: This looks super promising, I will try it as soon as I have some time! Thank you already!